# The difference between "public" and "public static"?

Tags: php, function, class, oop

What does `static` mean?

I know `public` means that it can be accessed from outside the class, and `private` only from inside the class…

Comment: public methods and properties are accessible only after instantiating class and is called via "->" sign. public static methods and properties can be accessed without need of instantiating class and can be called via "::".

Comment: nice question..

Comment: man I was so dumb back in 2011 :x

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Static means that it can be accessed without instantiating a class.  This is good for constants.

Static methods need to have no effect on the state of the object.  They can have local variables in addition to the parameters.

Modifiable static variables are risky. They act like a global variable, which can make the application fragile. Tracing where the variable was modified can be difficult.

Static methods are not risky. They can replace repeated code, increasing the likelihood the code will be well tested and correct.

Comment: Is static risky?

Comment: @ichimaru Static functions are not risky, but modifiable static variables can be.  They may act as a global variable, which can make the application fragile and tracing where the variable was modified difficult.  Static methods can replace repeated code, increasing the likelihood the code will be well tested and correct.

Answer (score 43):

**public**: Public declared items can be accessed everywhere.

**protected**: Protected limits access to inherited and parent
classes (and to the class that defines the item).

**private**: Private limits visibility only to the class that defines
the item.

**static**: A static variable exists only in a local function scope,
but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

**final**: Final keywords prevents child classes from overriding a
method by prefixing the definition with final. If the class itself is
being defined final then it cannot be extended.

---

Beside of PHP:

**transient**: A transient variable is a variable that may not
be serialized.

**volatile**: A variable that might be concurrently modified by multiple
threads should be declared volatile. Variables declared to be volatile
won't be optimized by the compiler because their value can change at
anytime.

Comment: what means serialized ?

Comment: You say about 'static'  that *"This is good for constants."* Why only that? According to my experience, it's good for most --if not all, exept Instance-- variables that are to be accessed from everywhere in a class!

Answer (score 17):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

> Declaring class properties or methods
>   as static makes them accessible
>   without needing an instantiation of
>   the class. A property declared as
>   static can not be accessed with an
>   instantiated class object (though a
>   static method can).

Answer (score 5):

An example: when use the `static` keyword, we cannot use `$this`

```
class Foo {
    private $foo='private';

    private function priv_func() {
        echo 'priv_method';
    }

    public static function get() {
        echo $this->foo;
        $this->priv_func();
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
$obj->get();
```

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in (…)

Comment: You can also use `self` for accessing static methods and static variables inside the same class. `self::priv_func();`

Comment: I feel like if this example had a bit more explanation is would really help me as there aren't any other examples on this page.  Unfortunately I don't really understand what you're trying to teach me.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
public class Methods_Test1 
{   
    public static void Display(String Name)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello There " + Name);
        System.out.println("I am from Display method");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        String name = sc.next();
        Obj.Display(name);

    }
```

The public static void Display(String name) method accessible as static method within its own class which can be accessed without creating object of the class where as the same method behaves as public for the outside classes which can be accessed by creating object.

Comment: is Obj defined here ? wont we get an error ?

at 
`Obj.Display(name);`