# Yii2: How to use map() to show two fields in a Select2?

Tags: yii2, map-function, yii-widgets

I am using a **Select2** widget for Yii2. It shows a list with the ids of the users.

I need to show two fields defined in my model called **Users**: **first_name_user** and **last_name_user**. Like this:

```
Daniel Gates
John Connor
John Doe
Maria Key
```

But I don't know how use **map()** to show more than one field.

```
<?= $form
    ->field($model, 'id_user')
    ->widget(\common\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
        'items' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Users::find()->orderBy('name_user')->all(), 'id_user', 'name_user')
    ])
?>
```

Comment: added an answer for you check if that helps you out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Model**

Add `use app\models\Users;` and `use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;` at top.

```
public function userList()
{
    $userList  = [];
    $users = Users::find()->orderBy('first_name_user')->all();

    $userList = ArrayHelper::map($users, 'id_user', function ($user) {
       return $user->first_name_user.' '.$user->last_name_user;
    });

    return $userList;
}
```

**_form**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id_user')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => $model->userList(),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select User'],
]) ?>
```

Comment: Why userList() function is static?

Comment: @RobySottini You can use function without object too. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527120/difference-between-public-and-public-static)

Comment: Nice solution. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use `data` option instead of `items` for `Select2`.
2. You need to modify your `query` to show the concatenated `first_name_user` and `last_name_user` as an alias and then return it along with the `id` column to be used in `Select2` by `ArrayHelper::map()`.

It's better to add a function to the model you are using to populate the form and return the results from there to the `ArrayHelper::map()`.
Your query should look like

```
function userList(){
return \app\models\Users::find()
       ->select([new \yii\db\Expression('[[id_user]],CONCAT([[first_name_user]]," ",[[last_name_user]]) as full_user_name')])
       ->orderBy('name_user')
       ->all();
}
```

Your form field should look like below

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'id_user')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model->userList(), 'id_user', 'full_user_name'),
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select User',
        'id' => 'id_user'
    ],
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_DEFAULT,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
?>
```

Comment: This CRUD comes from a table called Sports. Shoud I defined the userList() function in Users' model file or in Sport model file?

Comment: ideally it should be in user model, you just need to call it from whichever model you place it @Roby Sottini